# Cant kill session even after restarting browser

Tags: php, session-variables, session-cookies

I am having an issue right now with sessions. I use a log in script to do initial authentication, and then i authenticate at the begining of each protected page, and finally i *try* to log out (code below).

The files exist on my server using PHP 5.6. I am using Win10 and Chrome on my pc.

SYMPTOMS:

1. Although session vars are destroyed, i can still use the 'back' button in my browser to view a page that does authentication. When i dump $_SESSION vars on that page (which i browsed back to using the back button of the browser) all $_SESSION var are non existent - but the page still loads.
2. COOKIES are still there. I have set cookie lifetime in my php ini to 1 (one second) for testing... they are still there after i supposedly delete them. Even when set to 0, they are still there after i restart the browser.
3. After reading symptom 1 above, i think many of you will guess, correctly, that the session is still alive and well - even after i close the browser, restart it and type the url of one of the protected pages directly in the address bar i am still able to view the page, even though the $_SESSION var that checks for authentication does not exist.

Would really appreciate advice.

LOG IN SCRIPT

```
//this page is called (using require_once) by the page
    //that captures username and password
    session_start();

    //requirements
    require_once "../php/path.php";       //sets the server search path
    require_once "constants.php";         //does all the DEFINE stuff
    require_once HTML_HEADER;             //loads HTML code - doc type, head etc
    require_once DATABASE;                //does the dB connecting

    //collect the POST
    $uName = $_POST[uName];
    $uPsswd = $_POST[uPsswd];

    //build & execute sql query
    **SQL to retreive uName and password here if match then...**
        $_SESSION['approved'] = 'true';
        require_once MAIN_CONTENTS;  //main page after authentic log in
        exit;
```

AUTHENTICATE CODE CALLED USING require_once BY EACH PROTECTED PAGE

```
    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }//end if

  //what's the time Mr Wolf?!!!
  $now = time(); 

  //although session exists, are we logged in and approved? If not kill session & eixt.
  if (isset($_SESSION['approved']) && $_SESSION['approved'] != 'true'){
    require_once "killSession.php";
    require_once "notAuthorised.php";
    exit;
  }//end if

  if (!isset($_SESSION['approved'])){
    require_once "killSession.php";
    require_once "notAuthorised.php";    
    exit;
  }

  //if session exists, how old is it? If older than 'discard_after' then kill session.
  if (isset($_SESSION['discard_after']) && $now > $_SESSION['discard_after']) {
    require_once "killSession.php";
    require_once "notAuthorised.php";    
    exit;

  }//end if
  else {
    //logged in and approved so set timeout for 15 mins
    $_SESSION['discard_after'] = $now + 30;  
  }//end else
```

THE killSession FILE

```
//check to make sure session exists - start if not
  if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['approved']='false';
  }//end if


  //following code caused 'headers already sent...'
  //if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    //$params = session_get_cookie_params();
    //setcookie(session_name(),'',time() - 172800, '/', $params['domain'], $params['secure'], isset($params['httponly']));
  //}

session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most probably caused by the `POST` data still being stored in your browser. By clicking the back button, your user is authenticated again and a session is created.

To resolve this issue you can use the `POST-Redirect-GET` method.

```
<?php

// Has the session been set?
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// If a form is submitted, add the POSt data to a session
// and redirect
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $_SESSION['login_data'] = $_POST;
    unset($_POST);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}

// Check if user wants to login, authenticate and unset login data
if (isset($_SESSION['login_data'])) {
    // Authenticate
    unset($_SESSION['login_data']);
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" role="form" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username"

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Authenticate</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your rapid response and attempt to resolve this issues. Although your code didn't resolve my issue, your comment about BROWSER CACHE was SPOT ON! So for now i have used <meta> and 'header()' to disable page caching (although still some odd behaviour in Chrome... a separate issue)!